InitializeComponent doesn't exist in this content. WFP .NET
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
        serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
        conectarArduino();
    }

I revised the XAML file match with everything and it is correct. Yesterday evening was running with no problems but this morning I found this problem in every .cs file of my app. Whaat should I try more? I am confused. I am a novel programmer in internship, sorry if this is a silly question. :)

Confirm that your Namespaces are correct.

it is! I don't know why is not working haha, thanks

The missing function is generated when you build the application. Maybe try cleaning the solution and rebuilding.

It is a partial class. Check the corresponding xaml file if the namespace or file name differ. Otherwise just clean your solution (delete all "bin", "obj" and ".vs" folders) and rebuild again ... sometimes it is just voodoo of Visual Studio ;)

For everyone who want to know the solution, I delete the file obj where my project is located. When u run again the VS ide that file will be created correctly and that's all!! Thank you Sandman!
